# How can I convert a var type to int?

Tags: c#, asp.net, var

Here from the following, I am getting a var type variable in my code:

```
var FormID = from n in dtEnDate.AsEnumerable()
             where n.Field<int>("Tax_Setup_UID") ==
                   Convert.ToInt32(item.GetDataKeyValue("Tax_Setup_UID"))
             select n.Field<string>("FormID");
```

Here it is giving me the formid. Now I want to convert this var type variable to an int for next use and if I try without conversion it is giving me an error. But I can't do it.

Comment: var is **not** a type! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: means can't i do this?

Comment: Looks like you don't understand what `var` do. Please read documentation first..

Comment: @wudzik, the first sentence of the article you linked states "variables that are declared at method scope have an implicit type var". Furthermore, as the compiler infers the type, it seems not unreasonable for the question about casting it to other types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're returning `select n.Field<string>("FormID")`, so the actual type of `var FormID` will be `IEnumerable<string>`.

If you know the query will return one result, you can do something like:

```
int formID = int.Parse(FormID.First());
```

If `FormID` is an `int` in your database, change `n.Field<string>` to `n.Field<int>` and you can omit the `int.Parse()`.

Comment: it is working,thanks, answer is there for this question but why all are down voting me?

Comment: Probably because a bit of self-help and showing what you have tried is appreciated. If you'd have put a breakpoint after the code you've shown, you could've inspected the contents of `FormID` and ask a more accurate question or even solve it yourself. :)

Comment: i saw the contents and it is showing me the value also but that time i unable to use it, any way thanks for the best answer.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, as has been pointed out already, `var` is not a type of it's own. Instead it will take the type of the value being assigned to it. You can see which type that is by hovering over it in Visual Studio.

You should find in this instance it is of type `IEnumerable<string>`.

So the first thing you need to do is get the item that you want. Assuming you only expect a single result then you can do this:

```
var item = FormID.First();//FormID is probably not a good choice for this variable name
```

Then you can convert your `string` to an `int` as follows:

```
int i = int.Parse(item);
```

or

```
int i = Convert.ToInt32(item);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `var` is not a type, it's just shorthand for "any type, and the compiler must figure out which one".

Second, your code returns the field "FormID" as a `string`, not as an `int`, so your variable `FormID` will be an `IEnumerable<string>`.

If `FormID` is in fact an `int` in your `DataTable`, just `select n.Field<int>("FormID");` otherwise, you must convert the `string` to an `int`, for instance by selecting `Convert.ToInt32(n.Field<string>("FormID"))`.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to remember is, before storing value in var, once hover over the calling function and check what it actually returns. It'll give you a precise/clear idea of where to store the returned value in, and if any direct casting is available `[i.e. Convert.ToInt32 and TryParse etc. when returned type is object or .First/Last in case of Enumerable]`. This way, you'd be safe from the hacks of conversions in the later steps.